# Java - get data need to login from website then login and go to other page

Tags: java, http, authentication, web

I want to login to specific website, but in case to do that i need to get some hidden data from web. In all next sesions its diffrent so i have to keep sesion alive i think.
To check if im logged in i want to go to another page of this specific website (you have to be logged in to see it)

Ok so i get response and i get my info as LOGIN, and 2 of HIDDEN_NAME and HIDDEN_VALUE
then i want to login into form by post with my email, pass and this data needed to login.

This is how i do that and it aint working:

```
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A example that demonstrates how HttpClient APIs can be used to perform
 * form-based logon.
 */
public class webparser
{
    static String EMAIL;
    static String PASS;
    static String LOGIN = null;
    static String HIDDEN_NAME[] = new String[2];
    static String HIDDEN_VALUE[] = new String[2];
    //static ClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
    //static DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager);
    static DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    static HttpResponse response;
    static HttpEntity entity;
    static List<Cookie> cookies;
    static CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    static HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        clientFormLogin();
    }

    public static void clientFormLogin() throws Exception {

        httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new DefaultRedirectStrategy() {
            public boolean isRedirected(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context)  {
                boolean isRedirect=false;
                try {
                    isRedirect = super.isRedirected(request, response, context);
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (!isRedirect) {
                    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if (responseCode == 301 || responseCode == 302) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
        httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        getLoginData(httpGet("https://bannersbroker.com/user/login"));
        setLoginData(null, null);
        displayResponse(httpPostLogin("https://bannersbroker.com/user/login?event=doLogin"));
        //displayResponse(httpGet("http://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_dashboard/dashboard"));
        displayResponse(httpGet("https://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_ewallet/ewallet"));

        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    public static void setLoginData(String EMAIL, String PASS) {
        if (EMAIL != null)
            webparser.EMAIL = EMAIL;
        else
            webparser.EMAIL = "my@email.com";
        if (PASS != null)
            webparser.PASS = PASS;
        else
            webparser.PASS = "my_pass";
    }

    public static String httpPostLogin(String postHttp) {
        String responseBody = null;
        try {
            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(postHttp +
                    "&email=" + EMAIL +
                    "&pass=" + PASS + "&"+
                    LOGIN + "=Login&" +
                    HIDDEN_NAME[0] + "=" + HIDDEN_VALUE[0] + "&"+
                    HIDDEN_NAME[1] + "=" + HIDDEN_VALUE[1]);

            System.out.println("executing request " + httpost.getURI());
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);

            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", EMAIL));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", PASS));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(LOGIN, "Login"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(HIDDEN_NAME[0], HIDDEN_VALUE[0]));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(HIDDEN_NAME[1], HIDDEN_VALUE[1]));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, Consts.UTF_8));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost, httpContext);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());

            //DisplayPage(entity.getContent());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseBody;
    }

    public static String httpGet(String urlAddres) {
        String responseBody = null;
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlAddres);

            System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget, httpContext);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());

            //DisplayPage(entity.getContent());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);

            System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseBody;
    }

    public static void DisplayPage(InputStream is) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String str = "";
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("" + str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void displayResponse(String responseBody) {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseBody);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    }

    public static void getLoginData(String responseBody) {
        int length, temp, counter = 0;
        length = responseBody.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (responseBody.startsWith("hidden", i)) {
                temp = i;
                HIDDEN_NAME[counter] = responseBody.substring(temp + 13, temp + 81);
                HIDDEN_VALUE[counter] = responseBody.substring(temp + 90, temp + 123);
                System.out.println("HIDDEN_NAME[" + counter + "] = " + HIDDEN_NAME[counter]);
                System.out.println("HIDDEN_VALUE[" + counter + "] = " + HIDDEN_VALUE[counter]);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (responseBody.startsWith("document.write", i)) {
                temp = i;
                LOGIN = responseBody.substring(temp + 41, temp + 144);
                System.out.println("LOGIN = " + LOGIN);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how my console looks like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=E:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;E:\solsoft\BannersBrokerStatistic\target\classes;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\org\jibx\schema\net\java\org.jibx.schema.net.java.jnlp_6_0\1.0.8\org.jibx.schema.net.java.jnlp_6_0-1.0.8.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\org\jibx\jibx-run\1.2.4.5\jibx-run-1.2.4.5.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.1\joda-time-2.1.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3\1.1.3.4.O\xpp3-1.1.3.4.O.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\org\jibx\jibx-extras\1.2.4.5\jibx-extras-1.2.4.5.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\org\jdom\jdom\1.1.3\jdom-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3-alpha1\httpclient-4.3-alpha1.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3-alpha1\httpcore-4.3-alpha1.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Rafał\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.6\commons-codec-1.6.jar;E:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain webparser
executing request https://bannersbroker.com/user/login
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Initial set of cookies:
- [version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: kcbjr1br4fmqksb038663eenn3][domain: bannersbroker.com][path: /][expiry: null]
- [version: 0][name: __ct][value: 42d5a032bbbc0fc21d17da8f9ef0a6b7][domain: bannersbroker.com][path: /][expiry: Tue Mar 12 21:52:53 CET 2013]
HIDDEN_NAME[0] = _f6c043c1a1d767f2d447a43c32c878e9[_6911a65a36fbc4ec93ccccf911ead848]
HIDDEN_VALUE[0] = _fb664a024bce8eb09e9c63f41a60287c
HIDDEN_NAME[1] = _f6c043c1a1d767f2d447a43c32c878e9[_fda5de586c4828b18cb01983cc8e2961]
HIDDEN_VALUE[1] = _33b0402e97f2be1aca4e672dc3c23384
LOGIN = _f6c043c1a1d767f2d447a43c32c878e9[_0a1012405121479093b7fa787480e330][_03cede135af4bcc837cf48b43265795d]
Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Post logon cookies:
- [version: 0][name: PHPSESSID][value: kcbjr1br4fmqksb038663eenn3][domain: bannersbroker.com][path: /][expiry: null]
- [version: 0][name: __ct][value: 79fa3d8c1e5d3d823c9740c0894d479f][domain: bannersbroker.com][path: /][expiry: Tue Mar 12 21:52:53 CET 2013]
----------------------------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
it show source of https://bannersbroker.com/user/login
so wrong becous it should redictered to http://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_dashboard/dashboard 
    </html>
----------------------------------------
executing request https://bannersbroker.com/adpubcombo_ewallet/ewallet
----------------------------------------
null
----------------------------------------
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Moved Permanently
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:67)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:116)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:109)
    at webparser.httpGet(webparser.java:145)
    at webparser.clientFormLogin(webparser.java:77)
    at webparser.main(webparser.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

whats wrong ? why it aint working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of HttpClient API i use Jsoup

I created method to get login data

```
public Connection.Response getLoginData() {
        Connection.Response res = null;
        try {
            String html;
            int length, counter;

            res = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://bannersbroker.com//user/login?event=doLogin")
                    .execute();

            html = res.parse().toString();
            length = html.length();
            counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (html.startsWith("document.write", i)) {
                    name[counter] = html.substring(i + 41, i + 144);
                    value[counter] = "Login";
                    counter++;
                }
                if (html.startsWith("hidden", i)) {
                    name[counter] = html.substring(i + 13, i + 81);
                    value[counter] = html.substring(i + 90, i + 123);
                    counter++;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (NullPointerException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

then i do login with another method

```
public Connection.Response doLogin(Connection.Response res, String email, String pass) {
        Connection.Response res2 = null;
        try {
            res2 = Jsoup
                    .connect("https://bannersbroker.com//user/login?event=doLogin")
                    .cookies(res.cookies())
                    .data("email", email)
                    .data("pass", pass)
                    .data(name[0], value[0])
                    .data(name[1], value[1])
                    .data(name[2], value[2])
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (NullPointerException ioe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(RunFrame.getInstance(),
                    "Could not open connection to Banners Broker!",
                    "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        return res2;
    }
```

i call the methods in construcxtor of my class and send from one to another respons.
when i login i work on resposn from method `doLogin()`
this is how i pars data

```
doc = Jsoup
                    .connect(pageAddres)
                    .cookie("PHPSESSID", res.cookie("PHPSESSID"))
                    .get();
```